# Boxing/Unboxing in C#

Tags: c#, boxing, unboxing

I'm having trouble with a C# assignment dealing with boxing/unboxing. Here are the directions:

- Create an empty List of type object
- Add the following values to the list: 7, 28, -1, true, "chair"
- Loop through the list and print all values (Hint: Type Inference might 
  help here!)
- Add all values that are Int type together and output the sum

The trouble I am having is declaring a list that doesn't specify the data type so I can add multiple values of different data types to the list in the object (see Step 2).  Any advice?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly but are you searching for: ``List<object> listOfObjects = new List<object>();`` ?

Comment: Whoever wrote the instructions is confused about the meaning of "Type Inference".

Comment: List<object> listOfObjects = new List<object>(); worked! Thank you for the fast responses!  I simply had to cast the list itself as an object.

Comment: @TravisAlexanderTerrell That's literally the instructions in your requirements.  It *specifically* told you to do exactly that.

Comment: Yeah I simply read it wrong because I hadn't seen that done in code before so after I seen some actually code the instructions made more sense.

Comment: You have not seen it before because no one would usually create a list of `Object` because it is too generic. Instead one would use interfaces or inheritance to have a list of *related* objects that still differ in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add the values of the integers together. If that is the case, the following code will help you out.

```
var items = new List<object> { 7, 28, -1, true, "chair" };
int sum = 0;

foreach(var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(int))
        sum += (int)item;
}

// Now display the sum
Console.WriteLine($"The sum is: {sum}");
```

When an item is boxed, the type information is still obtainable from the `GetType()` method that is inherited from the object class. You'll just have to see if it is an integer and you can go ahead and cast that and add it to your sum.

Comment: @TravisAlexanderTerrell, does it answer your question or do you still need more?

Comment: No your explanation was extremely clear.  Thank you!

Comment: Ok, in that case, to avoid having people come and try to give additional answers, please mark it as accepted. ;)

Comment: Is that the green check mark?

Comment: I believe that would be it. It looked like you accepted it and now it isn't. Should I add something?

Comment: No it is solved thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<object> objectList = new List<object>();
objectList.Add("This is a string");
objectList.Add(64);
objectList.Add(154.2f);
```

Everything is an object. Therefore, you can add it to an object list.

```
for(int i=0; i < objectList.Length; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine(objectList[i].GetType().ToString());
}
```

The for loop demonstrates how to get the type of the current element.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can assign *anything* to the `object` type. Therefore, you should declare your list as:

```
List<object> myList = new List<object> { 7, 28, -1, true, "chair" };
```

Since `object` is a reference type while `int`s like `7`, `28` and `-1` are value types, they are "converted" to a reference type at runtime. This is called "boxing". Here, `7, 28, -1, true` are boxed because they are all value types. `"chair"` is not boxed because `String` is a reference type.

Also, if the `new List<object> { 7, 28, -1, true, "chair" }` syntax looks new to you, it's the same as:

```
List<object> myList = new List<object>();
myList.Add(7);
myList.Add(28);
myList.Add(-1);
myList.Add(true);
myList.Add("chair");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty List of type object

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
```

Add the following values to the list: 7, 28, -1, true, "chair"

```
list.Add(7);
list.Add(28);
list.Add(-1);
list.Add(true);
list.Add("chair");
```

Loop through the list and print all values and check type

```
foreach (object item in list)
{
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(int))
    {
        //int type
    }
    else if (item.GetType() == typeof(bool))
    {
        // bool type
    }
    else if (item.GetType() == typeof(string))
    {
        //string type
    }
    else
    {
        //other type
    }
}
```

All values that are Int type together and output the sum

```
int sum = list.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(int))
.Sum(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
```

I hope it will help you.